# send socket data to specific ejs page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, ejs

I am using express plus ejs as view engine in node.I am facing a problem while emitting the message through socket. My main file name
 is `index.js` and the view file is inside `pages/messages` that is ejs
file. i am using

```
app.get('/messages/:id', function(req,res)          {
            res.render('pages/messages');

            });

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {       console.log(msg);    socket.emit('chat message', msg);

        });   
});
```

Above code i am using in the main file that is index.js and the below code as front end

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

 <script>   var socket = io(); 
    $(document).ready(function()
{   $('form').submit(function(e){  
 alert('1');    
e.stopPropagation();    
e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val(), '');
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;   });
             socket.on('chat message', function(req, res){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(res));
               });  }); 
</script>




 <ul id="messages"></ul>

      <form action="" >
          <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
```

after emit li contain empty data.

Comment: Please write in a more readable format.

Comment: hello aman i can't actually the editor can't give me permission to add more formatting

Comment: please check is it readable now?

Comment: I have edited further.

Comment: okay thanks please solve my problemam new to node

Answer (score 0):

`req,res` params are for express routes and not for `socket events`. Do following changes and check whether it works:

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());

socket.on('chat message', function(data){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data));
});
```

In you backend, change this to should solve echo problem:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {             
       console.log(msg);        
       socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);

     });   
   });
```

Comment: its showing data in li but its repeating like this
    "simmi
    simmi
    happy
    happy
    happy"

Comment: i have to send this msg through web service to second user who is online with me